# How to get correct WSDL URL when hosting a WCF service behind an Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, wcf, wsdl, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

We are in the process of migrating services from on-premise to Azure, and we are now hosting a legacy WCF service an Azure App Service. To make it backwards compatible with existing clients, it needs to be available through `{domainNameHere}.com/services`.

There are also other services that should be accessible through the same domain, for example `{domainNameHere}.com/api`. We have set up an Azure Application Gateway to route requests to different App Services based on the request paths, and have set `{domainNameHere}.com` to point to the Application Gateway IP.

This works well for all the services except for the WCF service. It is accessible in the browser at `https://{domainNameHere}.com/services/exports.svc`, but the WSDL URIs at that page shows the `azurewebsites.net` URIs instead of our custom domain. When clients attempt to access the service, they get the following error:

```cs
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
'There was no endpoint listening at https://{domainNameHere}.com/services/export.svc
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.'

Inner Exception
WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

We have tried to use `useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress` in the WCF config to no avail.

Here is the WCF configuration, all in code. The `endpoint` URI is `https://{domainNameHere}.com/services/exports.svc`.

```
public static void Configure<T>(ServiceConfiguration config, Uri endpoint) where T : class
{
    // Configure service behavior
    config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpsGetEnabled = true });
    config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });

    var serviceCredential = config.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>();
    if (serviceCredential == null)
    {
        serviceCredential = new ServiceCredentials();
        config.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceCredential);
    }

    serviceCredential.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
    serviceCredential.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CredentialsValidator();

    config.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(T), GetBinding(), endpoint);
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the Azure App service, and from your code snippets,  I don't see how the code creates a host to host WCF services. If it's IIS or a console program, it creates a host to run the service.<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %> or    using (ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
            {
                sh.Open();

Comment: I finally figured it out. The Application Gateway made requests to the WCF service using HTTP, but the WCF service only replied on HTTPS. As soon as I updated the Application Gateway to make requests using HTTPS it was working as expected.

Comment: @ikoddn  You could post your solution as an answer, this may help someone who also face this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The Application Gateway made requests to the WCF service using HTTP, but the WCF service only replied on HTTPS. As soon as I updated the Application Gateway to make requests using HTTPS it was working as expected.